# Android ACTION_MOVE doesn't work

Tags: android

it might be a dumb question, but i don't know why ACTION_MOVE doesn't get called. I need to update a variable using touched x coordinate, but when i press down and hold, then move around the variable doesn't change.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int ptrId = 0;
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (event.getAction() & event.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        screenTouches += 1;
        ourSurfaceView.screenTouched(event.getX(), event.getY());
        ourSurfaceView.screenTouched2(event.getX(), event.getY());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        screenTouches -= 1;
        ourSurfaceView.screenReleased(event.getX(), event.getY());
        ourSurfaceView.screenReleased2(event.getX(), event.getY());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        ptrId = action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
        screenTouches += 1;
        int ptrIdx = event.findPointerIndex(ptrId);
        ourSurfaceView.screenTouched(event.getX(ptrId), event.getY(ptrId));
        ourSurfaceView.screenTouched2(event.getX(ptrId), event.getY(ptrId));
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        ptrId = action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
        screenTouches -= 1;
        ourSurfaceView.screenReleased(event.getX(ptrId), event.getY(ptrId));
        ourSurfaceView
                .screenReleased2(event.getX(ptrId), event.getY(ptrId));
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        ourSurfaceView.screenMove(event.getX(ptrId), event.getY(ptrId));
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

EDIT:

return false; worked, there was a mistake at my code elsewhere so that's why i thought it didnt work.

Comment: i tried, but doesnt work. :(

Comment: i added
Log.v("Moveable", "X = " + x + " Y = " + y + "\n");
and it shows coordinates well

Comment: so theres a problem elsewhere

Comment: I believe it's something to do with the mask you're applying. I suggest searching (Google) on the proper way to handle masking the fingers.

Comment: try return false and delete event.ACTION_MASK. It should work

Comment: return false actually worked, there was a mistake at my code elsewhere. Thanks a lot.